# Faceting in Algolia search engine index

Tags: algolia

I'm working on integrating the Algolia search engine using nodeJS, having a bit of trouble getting proper facets for an array properties in Algolia
For example: Having an items property in a record of the Algolia index which contains data in a given format:-

```
{
  id:1,
  category:'books',
  items:  [
      { id: 1, name: 'C Programming Language', instock: true },
      {
        id: 2,name: 'Head First C',instock: false,
      },
    ];
}
```

We want to get only those items name in the facet for which the instock value is true.
Applied distinct on items.name and filter by instock:true still getting 'C Programming Language' and 'Head First C' both names in facets.

Expected result: I should get only 'C Programming Language' in the items name facet if records are filtered by instock value true.

Is there some sort of option I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is inside out for an index.

The individual titles should be the records, with "category" as an attribute of those records. With your current object structure, the entire category is a record.

Something like this should work:

```
  {
    id:1,
    name: 'C Programming Language',
    instock: true,
    category:'books'
   },
   {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Head First C',
    instock: false,
    category:'books'
  },
```

Then you can filter on titles that are `category:'books'` and `instock:true`